# Using a laptop as a monitor

Tags: raspberry-pi

I was just given a raspberry pi (Woo!!) but I have no monitor. I was wondering if I could use my laptop as a monitor. Or whether I could use my android tablet as a monitor.

Thanks

Comment: possible dupe for the laptop screen question: http://superuser.com/questions/428728/raspberry-pi-and-laptop-screen?rq=1

Answer (score 1):

If your laptop (or tablet) has an HDMI video input it will work. However, this is unlikely. There *might* be software out there that would allow you to do this via the USB port, but I am not sure off the top of my head.

A better idea would be to use a television set that has an HDMI port.